# CSS - double pseudo classes.. is this possible

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

```
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked ~ .onoffswitch-inner:hover {
   background: #0095cd;
}
```

Is this possible?

Basically I want a hover class on the .onoffswitch-inner when the sibling checkbox is checked.

Comment: Looks like valid CSS to me. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes it wasn't working.. seems i may well have something else at play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead. It works:

http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/z38Y6/1/

HTML

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"/> Check this box
    <div class="onoffswitch-inner">And hover here</div>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked ~ .onoffswitch-inner:hover {
   background: #0095cd;
}
```

Comment: i don't get it i was doing what i thought was exactly that and it wasn't working! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EyjEZ/7/

Note: The label tag should have preferably a for attribute which than can be referenced to the checkbox. For accessibility and usability reasons. Thus screen readers lik it and it enlarges the area to click on and adds tab focus.

This will make any sibling element of the checked checkbox with that class get that hover style. See: http://jsfiddle.net/YRe3n/1/

IE 8 does not support :checked

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
 <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="foo" name="bar" /><label for="foo">Foo</label>
 <p class="onoffswitch-inner">This is the inner</p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked ~ .onoffswitch-inner:hover {
   background: #0095cd;
}
```

This would work as well if you need to target the next sibling element only.

```
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + label + .onoffswitch-inner:hover {
   background: #0095cd;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2scGR/1/

Comment: ie8 is dead IMO. I am sure i read that windows will stop supporting winXP in april.. thus finally the end of ie8! As for screen readers.. yes, however this app is not really designed for the hard of seeing.. and this check box would the least of their concern. Putting the content in the label is one less calc for the server to do and one tiny bit less code for the client to download.

Comment: IE 8 is at 7% in the US - http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-browser_version-US-monthly-201302-201402 + many companies do not update their machines that fast.
You never know if one of your end-users is visually-impaired. You could even use this as as unique selling point.

Comment: that is very true.. but IMO you have to think about your target market.. is my target in that 7%.. big slow companies or old aged pensioners in the sticks.. and what happends in april after ms drops support for xp?